# Send instruction to arduino through micro usb in android phone via app

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb, arduino

I want to send an instruction to Arduino through an android app over the micro USB port. 
For example, on clicking a button in the app there should glow an led connected to Arduino and the connection should be done via the micro USB port on android phone. I've done the same using bluetooth connection. How should I proceed on this? Or what should be the changes in the code?

Via bluetooth:

```
package com.example.bluetooth;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  int red_count=0;
  int yellow_count=0;
  int green_count=0;
  int white_count=0;
  private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";

  Button red_button,yellow_button,green_button,white_button,reset_button;
  Handler h;

  final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;        // Status  for Handler
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

  // SPP UUID service
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
  private static String address = "20:13:01:18:05:08";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    red_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button);    
    yellow_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button);
    green_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
    white_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.white_button);
    reset_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);

    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                    red_button.setEnabled(true);
                    yellow_button.setEnabled(true);
                    green_button.setEnabled(true);
                    white_button.setEnabled(true);
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();

    red_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          red_count++;
          yellow_count=0;
          green_count=0;
          white_count=0;
          red_button.setText(""+red_count);
          yellow_button.setText("");
          green_button.setText("");
          white_button.setText(""); 
          mConnectedThread.write("1");  // Send "1" via Bluetooth
      }
    });

    yellow_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          yellow_count++;
          red_count=0;
          green_count=0;
          white_count=0;
          yellow_button.setText(""+yellow_count);
          red_button.setText("");
          green_button.setText("");
          white_button.setText("");
          mConnectedThread.write("2");  // Send "2" via Bluetooth
        }
      });

    green_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          green_count++;
          red_count=0;
          yellow_count=0;
          white_count=0;
          green_button.setText(""+green_count);
          red_button.setText("");
          yellow_button.setText("");
          white_button.setText("");
          mConnectedThread.write("3");  // Send "3" via Bluetooth
        }
      });

    white_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          white_count++;
          red_count=0;
          green_count=0;
          yellow_count=0;
          white_button.setText(""+white_count);
          red_button.setText("");
          green_button.setText("");
          yellow_button.setText("");
          mConnectedThread.write("4");  // Send "4" via Bluetooth
        }
      });

    reset_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          white_count=0;
          red_count=0;
          green_count=0;
          yellow_count=0;
          white_button.setText("");
          red_button.setText("");
          green_button.setText("");
          yellow_button.setText("");
          mConnectedThread.write("0");  // Send "0" via Bluetooth
        }
      });
  }

  private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
          try {
              final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
              return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
          } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
      }
      return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    /*try {
      btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }*/

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    try     {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
      } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
  }

  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                    h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,first of all i don't know anything about adruino coding,but in-order to communicate with usb devices android uses USB Host Api,goto the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) for that.and here is a tutorial that may help interfacing android with Adruino,
 [how to communicate between the Arduino Uno and your computer using plain USB bulk and control transfers](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=427)
Hope this helps